# Update jQuery Easy Pie Chart percentage with click event

Tags: jquery, html, charts, pie-chart

Basically I need to update the pie chart/progress bar as according to this form wizard layout, I've attached the onClick element to the next and previous ids but I cannot get it to increment by 25% or decrement by 25% as according to the value.

Basically there are 4 steps and it needs to backwards and forwards with the pie chart reacting accordingly, **any help will be greatly appreciated**. Here is the [wizard](http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.3/form-wizard.html) that I am using and the code is as below;

```
var myValue = 25;

            $('#next').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    $('.easy-pie-chart.percentage').data('easyPieChart').update(myValue + 25);
                });
            });
```

Comment: I am using easy pie chart: http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must multiply the value with 125% or 75%. This is all.

```
var myValue = 28;
$('#update').on('click', function() {
    $('.easy-pie-chart').data('easyPieChart').update(
        Math.round(myValue*1.25)
);
```